# Scheduling/Queueing Tasks Django/Celery

Tags: django, celery, scheduled-tasks, queueing

I'd like to add a scheduling option to **allow user to manually input a date and time that would delay their post to be published to that specific date/time.** So if the user uploads five posts in one day but only wants to publish one per day, then they could input a specific date and time for each post to be published (i.e. Post #1 publish on 1/8/18 3:30pm, Post #2 publish on 1/13/18 4:00pm, etc.)

Thinking about using Celery to approach this problem. **Having trouble visualizing how to connect Celery Tasks to the Post Form (or Model) so user can have the option to adjust the timing according to their scheduling needs**. If you could explain with visual examples and where the examples are taking place (i.e. views.py, etc.) that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could use signals (post-save ) https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/signals/ and schedule the celery task